# How to protect DRM without password challenges using Adobe Access SDK?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat-sdk

I'm sorry if my question sounds a little bit stupid.

I want to protect PDF files using Adobe Access SDK. But I am curious, is there another way to protect DRM without using password challenges?

Comment: What kind of protection are you after? And for which pdf viewers shall it work?

Comment: I want to encrypt the PDF files, and prevent edit/copy also. If an attacker could get that file, they was unable to view it, I mean.

Comment: There are DRM solutions out there which may provide the required protection but they will only work on specific pdf viewers and will require you to install specific plugins for those viewers.

Comment: Could you give me some more details? Which DRM solutions and which PDF viewers? Do it cost much on license and development?
I also have to balance between cost and security.

Comment: I don't know which solutions there currently are. I assume usually only adobe reader can serve as viewer but add mentioned above, I'm not sure about the state of art. And of course you won't get complete security, screen shots will always be possible.